# Reproduce default variable scrolling speed for listview

Tags: listview, winapi

### INTRODUCTION:

User starts multiple selection of items, like in the below image:

[image]

Then he extends this selection beyond last vertically visible item.

Listview starts to autoscroll down, but its autoscroll speed *varies* depending on the mouse position.

### PROBLEM:

I would like to know how to reproduce this behavior since there is no API that does this for me. Therefore I must do this on my own, but was unable to find relevant examples to do so.

To make things perfectly clear, I want to *reproduce default Windows* behavior, not to roll my own autoscroll logic.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

I have used Spy++ to try and find WM_TIMER message that performs described behavior but was not able to find anything helpful.

All I was able to determine was that listview often calls `0x10C1` message, which is not officially documented. Googling helped me to find out that this message is called `LVM_GETACCVERSION` but that is all I was able to find. No documentation for this message, nor code example exists, or so it seems.

I have Googled for the equation that drives autoscroll logic but found nothing.

Being out of any other ideas, I turned here for help.

### QUESTION:

How can we reproduce default autoscroll behavior described in the `INTRODUCTION` section ?

Again, to make things perfectly clear, I want to *reproduce default Windows* behavior, not to roll my own autoscroll logic.

Comment: You emphasize the word "reproduce" default Windows behavior, but Windows doesn't do progressive speed scrolling on drag-n-drop... So I guess you DO need to roll your own logic.

Comment: To the *anonimous* downvoter, and others who just can not read simple English: the question is NOT about drag and drop, but about reproducing default scrolling behavior when user tries to mark multiple items for selection in listview. Please read carefully the question, and look carefully at the image I provided. I have put a lot of effort into this question, I really do not ask that much, just to actually read the question.

Comment: Why do you want to reproduce its behavior, instead of just using the original ListView control?

Comment: @Codeguard: I would like to apply the same scrolling logic for drag and drop, when user moves cursor outside of listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The algorithm is simple enough:**

1. Calculate number of pixels between control's client rect and mouse cursor.
2. `ScrollWindow()` by that many pixels.
3. Repeat immediately until mouse is up.

**Researching scroll amount**
The test code is provided for vertically scrolled listview.

Subclass listview:

```
g_OriginalListViewProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(m_hwndListView, GWLP_WNDPROC);
SetWindowLongPtr(m_hwndListView, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)ListViewProc);
```

New window procedure:

```
int GetCursorOffset(HWND a_Window)
{
    RECT listRect;
    GetClientRect(a_Window, &listRect);
    ClientToScreen(a_Window, (POINT*)&listRect + 0);
    ClientToScreen(a_Window, (POINT*)&listRect + 1);

    POINT cursorPos;
    GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);

    if (cursorPos.y < listRect.top)
        return cursorPos.y - listRect.top;
    else if (cursorPos.y > listRect.bottom)
        return cursorPos.y - listRect.bottom;

    return 0;
}

WNDPROC g_OriginalListViewProc = 0;
LRESULT ListViewProc(HWND a_HWND, UINT a_Message, WPARAM a_WParam, LPARAM a_LParam)
{
    switch (a_Message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            static int lastPos = 0;

            int scrollPos = GetScrollPos(a_HWND, SB_VERT);
            int delta = scrollPos - lastPos;
            lastPos = scrollPos;

            TRACE(_T("Ticks=%d Pos=%06d Delta=%05d Offs=%04d\n"), GetTickCount(), scrollPos, delta, GetCursorOffset(a_HWND));
        }
        break;
    }

    return g_OriginalListViewProc(a_HWND, a_Message, a_WParam, a_LParam);
}
```

Scroll the listview and observe that scroll_amount == offset_from_control.

**Researching trigger**
Open task manager, start scrolling. You will see CPU load spike to 100% on one processor core. That proves that they scroll in a busy loop instead of handling some timer.

**Researching loop**
On parent's window, `SetTimer()` to something like 5000ms, put a breakpoint on timer's message arrival and start scrolling. When timer hits, you will see something like that on callstack:

```
MyExe.exe!DialogProc(WM_TIMER)
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()
user32.dll!UserCallDlgProcCheckWow()
user32.dll!DefDlgProcWorker()
user32.dll!_DefDlgProcW@16()
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()
comctl32.dll!_ListView_DragSelect@12()
comctl32.dll!_ListView_HandleMouse@24()
comctl32.dll!_ListView_WndProc@16()
...
```

That shows that `_ListView_DragSelect` runs an internal message loop, processing any messages between scroll iterations.

**Extra notes**

1. You need to `SetCapture` on `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` to receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE` when mouse leaves control's rect. Don't forget to `ReleaseCapture` later.
2. Instead of making a loop with processing messages, you can instead post yourself a custom window message after each iteration and handle it once it arrives.
3. Instead of busy loop, you can set a timer and handle it ([ReactOS has implemented it with a timer](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d8/d3e/dll_2win32_2comctl32_2listview_8c_a228605ce765f117595830ac1f41f1f0e.html#a228605ce765f117595830ac1f41f1f0e)). This way, you won't spike to 100% CPU, and scrolling speed won't depend on user's CPU speed.
4. You can stop your loop/timer when mouse re-enters control's area and handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` as usual.

Comment: I have awarded you the bounty, upvoted and officially accepted the answer. Generally speaking,I understand your instructions so I think I will manage to implement them. Thank you for your effort, I highly appreciate it. Best regards until next time.